# Can Apache Kafka be used with Desktop Application

Tags: apache-kafka

I am creating a new desktop application in WPF. Objective of the application is to read data from a device and show real time charts in WPF clients. At the same time I want to save incoming data to database. There are few other operation to be performed on incoming data in parallel. The connected device produce data at around 1000 messages per second. I was trying to evaluate different message queuing systems for this scenario and came across Apache Kafka as one of the alternative. I have few questions regarding the same:

- Is this even valid use case for Kafka? In other words, should we even use Kafka for desktop applications?
- Are there any example project/POC for the same? I cannot find any such examples.
- What about problem of shipping the application? Since we are not going to have any central server for desktop applications, we have to run / deploy kafka on each user's system.